# how can I add the rule to this program?

Tags: prolog

Suppose you have the following program loaded in prolog:

```
?- listing.
fast(ann).
slow(bob).
slow(norm).
true.
?-
```

How can I add the following rule to this program?

```
faster(X,Y) :- fast(X), slow(Y).
```

Can some one help me write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Put the rule in a file, say `faster.pl`, then load that file with `[faster].`
2. Issue `[user].` at the prompt, then type the rule and issue EOF (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in SWI-Prolog).

Answer (score 0):

Prolog [database](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.13%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/db.html%27%29%29) is dynamic: modification to rules' base can be accomplished with [assertz](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assertz/1)/1 and retract/1. Then, adding to @larsman answer, you could write

```
?- assertz((faster(X,Y) :- fast(X), slow(Y))).
```

After that, from your facts base:

```
?- faster(X,Y).
X = ann,
Y = bob ;
X = ann,
Y = norm.
```